# Is "in favour of John" a resultative here?

Tags: syntax, verbs

In the sentence, "The judge settled the dispute in favour of John", is "in favour of John" a resultative? I am being asked to explain what this string shows about the verb "settle".

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what do _you_ think?

Comment: "The dispute" is Od of "settled" and the PP "in favour of John" is complement of "settled"

Comment: That works, but I'd prefer to consider _in favour of John_ as a complement of the VP _settled the dispute_.